# Ubuntu 16.04 LTS getting hung up after installation at restart now

Tags: 16.04, boot, partitioning

Every time I try installing ubuntu 16.04 LTS from bootable pendrive in my new laptop (UEFI disabled (in Legacy mode), 128GB SSD and 1TB HDD), the installation runs fine, it shows me installation is complete and that I have to restart, but when I click "restart now" it hangs up. If i force shutdown by pressing power-key and turn it back on, I get to the login page, I am able to successfully log in but it gets stuck after that without showing anything on the screen.

I created '/' partition and '/boot' on SSD and '/home' and swap on HDD. I  don't want to dual-boot, I want pure ubuntu.

Please help.

Comment: Even if installing Ubuntu only, always use UEFI mode for UEFI machines. And there's no need for a separate `/boot`. That said you probably is likely related to graphics drivers (Nvidia?) and not with the installation method.

Comment: yes it has 16GB graphic cards, so how should I solve it?

Comment: also, if I do not create '/boot' then should I use all of SSD (i.e 128GB for '/')? I also have to choose a partition to install boot-loader, hence I thought if I used up all of SSD for '/' then I wont be able to install boot-loader so I also created '/boot' and selected this partition for boot-loader

Comment: I have tried both 'installing 3rd party application' and not installing them..none of them seems to work.. what should I do?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I install Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6328/how-do-i-install-ubuntu) and also read this https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI in order to understand your hardware and the method. Disable Legacy to assure it boots and install in the correct mode. Use this https://askubuntu.com/a/38834/692175 to learn how to add the `nomodeset` boot parameter required until the Nvidia drivers are installed.