# Ubuntu Installation stuck on "Restart Now"

Tags: 16.04, boot, nvidia, system-installation, 17.10

I'm trying to install Ubuntu (tried both 16.04 & 17.10) on my new laptop that comes with FreeDOS (MSI GS63VR 16GB GTX 1060).

Installation itself is ok and then I get to the final step where I should press "Restart Now" to use my newly installed Ubuntu.

After I press the button, I get stuck on that screen and the machine doesn't restart.  If I force a shutdown and then try to start up again I get to the login page but after filling my password and pressing enter I'm stuck again on a desktop with no icons/pointer/anything.

I haven't done anything out of the ordinary in the installation process, I'm not doing dual boot or anything. I found [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/992736/ubuntu-16-04-lts-getting-hung-up-after-installation-at-restart-now) issue which seems to be just like mine but there's no solution.

Any thoughts?

EDIT: Previous boot configuration was Legacy and I've just tried UEFI + Disabled Secure Boot and got the same results, stuck on restart now/login page.

Comment: Please try to disable secure boot in BIOS.

Comment: I just did that and also changed from Legacy to UEFI boot. Same thing.