# Installing Ubuntu on clean laptop

Tags: 16.04, boot, grub2, uefi

I am trying to install Ubuntu 16.04.4 on a laptop with no other OS installed on it. The laptop is a MSI gp62mvr-6rf. I have the most up to date BIOS. I have tried a million things that I have read suggested on here as well as other sites. I turned off secure boot, I tried installing on Legacy, UEFI, UEFI with CSM.

Every time I install Ubuntu 16.04.4, I connect to my Wi-Fi, I download updates while installing (have tried not doing this), I install media drivers (I have also tried not doing this), I select Erase disk and install Ubuntu. I have a 256 GB SSD (and a 1TB HDD, but I am not utilizing that at all, the HDD is completely empty). I get through the rest of the installer, it completes and says: "Installation is complete. You need to restart the computer to in order to use the new installation. Restart Now. I click Restart Now, and the "loading" cursor appears for a few seconds, then disappears and I can no longer press or do anything (frozen). I force turn off my computer, and when I boot back in there's always something wrong, like it's not displaying grub2, or if it does display grub2, when I boot into Ubuntu I can't login (it freezes after passing the login screen) etc.

Does anyone have any suggestions on what I can do to make this work???

History: I used to have Windows 10 & Ubuntu 16.04 installed on this same SSD, and everything worked perfectly. I needed to redo some of the partitions on the SSD to clean some stuff up, I backed up all of my information externally, and have been trying to reinstall Ubuntu onto a non-partitioned 256 GB SSD, and I have been running into the above problems.

Comment: That is being done correctly. I have 2 disks as it states above in my question. 1 1TB HDD, and 1 256GB SSD. It is installing it on the 256 GB SSD, I am 100% sure about this.

Comment: I have deleted my post because it was a bad response, you are right, I apologize, I didn't entirely read your post initially but now that I have, you appear to be doing everything correctly. The "Erase disk and install Ubuntu"  should definitely work and the fact that you have had Windows and Ubuntu installed before on the same disk which have worked indicates that it is the drive your laptop boots from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, after much research...

[Ubuntu Installation stuck on "Restart Now"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1015510/ubuntu-installation-stuck-on-restart-now)

https://gabstutorials.wordpress.com/2017/06/15/install-ubuntu-16-04-on-a-msi-gp62mvr-laptop/

http://www.linuxandubuntu.com/home/how-to-install-latest-nvidia-drivers-in-linux

> * I’ve had issues with the 16.04.3 update and clean install… I’m trying to figure out what went wrong with this update. Stay away from 16.04.3 for now

This is the same problem in 16.04.03, 16.04.04, and 17.10.1. Also has a different problem in 18.04-daily build (won't even start up installer). Steps I took to fix:

1. Install the latest [BIOS](https://www.msi.com/Laptop/support/GP62MVR-6RF-Leopard-Pro#down-bios).
2. Turn off secure boot.
3. Download [ubuntu-16.04.4-desktop-amd64.iso](http://releases.ubuntu.com/releases/16.04.4/)
4. Download [Rufus 2.8](https://rufus.akeo.ie/)
5. Follow this [tutorial](https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-windows) on how to make a bootable USB
6. Follow this [tutorial](https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-install-ubuntu-desktop#0) on how to install Ubuntu
7. The installer will complete, click Restart Now. **This will not exit cleanly, force power off**
8. Boot normally, **do not login**. Press Ctrl+Alt+F2, login.
9. Run the command: `sudo apt-get purge nvidia* && sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers && sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install nvidia-384 -y`
10. After it has finished run the command `sudo shutdown -r now` **This may or may not exit cleanly, force power off if it does not**
11. On next boot, everything should be working 100%.

tl;dr : Download newest BIOS for MSI gp62mvr-6rf, revert to default settings, turn off secure boot, install Ubuntu 16.04.04 (this will **not** cleanly install. Run `sudo apt-get purge nvidia* && sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers && sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install nvidia-384 -y`, then run: `sudo shutdown -r now`, force power off if necessary, boot, everything should be working.

Comment: Congrats! I am glad that you were able resolve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try something else option while installing and choose your drive, select mount point as '/' and install bootloader on the same drive. If you still can't boot, then live boot again and check for the boot flag( if it's there on your ssd), if it's not there change it to ssd. Let me know if it works.

Comment: I do not think that that will help anything but I will try that. I once again (as stated in other comments) know that it is the boot drive. The main problem that I am having here is it completely freezes during install on the Restart Now step...

Comment: This did not work.